# Does Eclipse Ganymede have a mouse-click bug in the Navigator view?

Tags: eclipse, ganymede, navigator, eclipse-3.4

I've had to downgrade from Galileo to Ganymede in order to use the version of the FlexBuilder plugin that we are licensed for.  Since the downgrade, I have several times accidentally dragged files or entire folders from one part of my project into another (or even into another project).  I blamed this on fatfingers the first couple times, but I just now watched it do it to me on what I definitely know to have been a single left click on the folder that the file ended up moving to.

Does anybody know if this is a known issue with Ganymede?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

Here are the [known DnD (Drag and Drop) issues with the CommonNavigator in Eclipse 3.4.x](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?type1-0-0=substring;field1-0-3=status_whiteboard;field0-0-0=product;field1-0-2=short_desc;type0-0-1=substring;field0-0-1=component;value1-0-3=dnd;type1-0-1=substring;value1-0-1=dnd;type1-0-2=substring;value0-0-2=CommonNavigator;type1-0-3=substring;value1-0-2=dnd;type0-0-3=substring;query_format=advanced;value0-0-3=CommonNavigator;field0-0-3=status_whiteboard;value1-0-0=dnd;version=3.4;version=3.4.1;version=3.4.2;field0-0-2=short_desc;value0-0-1=CommonNavigator;type0-0-0=substring;value0-0-0=CommonNavigator;field1-0-0=product;type0-0-2=substring;field1-0-1=component), none of them describing a scenario which would be close of what you are experiencing.

Comment: A helpful link, thanks.  This is sort of a "proving a negative" question, so it's going to be hard to find an answer I can call accepted.  For what it's worth, switching from my trackball to the macbook touchpad seems to have made it go away, which is kind of a high price to pay.

Comment: @Brian: interesting feedback. I concur with you, my answer is not one "to be accepted";) Just a first element of response, hoping for others to have a better answer.